# `when` statement with multiple arguments in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, conditional-statements

```
data class Vehicle(val name: String, val category: String,val subCategory: String, val region: String)

fun main() {
    val newVehicle = Vehicle("Mitsubishi","Saloon", "Mini", "Kenya")
    val newVehicle2 = Vehicle("Mitsubishi 2","Saloon 2", "Mini 2", "Kenya 2")
    when(newVehicle.name || newVehicle.region) {
        "Mitsubishi 2" -> {
            print("Is Mitsubishi 2")
        }
        "Kenya" -> {
            print("Is Kenya")
        }
    }
}
```

Consider the code block above, is it possible to have multiple arguments to avoid repeating checks for the conditions for both `Vehicle.name` and `Vehicle.region` ? This fails with the error: `Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Boolean was expected`

Comment: What would `when(newVehicle.name || newVehicle.region)` mean? What do you expect the code to do here? Please state your expected output.

Comment: Or even better: rewrite the code so that it _compiles_, using repeated checks for both `Vehicle.name` and `Vehicle.region`, so that we know exactly what you are trying to do. Then we can try to get rid of the repetition.

Comment: @Sweeper I would like the condition to be checked against the two arguments, say if `neVehicle.name == "Mitsubishi 2"` OR `newVehicle.region == "Mitsubishi 2"`  then print for this case or /execute the block.

Comment: You can just use that as the expression then. Make sure whatever expression you put inside a `when` block, should return a boolean value. The code you posted above doesn't

Comment: You can use something like `vehicle.name == "xyz" || vehicle.region =="abc"` inside the when condition block

Comment: What if the first branch matches the first thing, and the second branch matches the second thing? Do you execute the first branch, the second branch, or both? For example (using your made up syntax here), `when ("a" || "b") { "a" -> { ... } "b" -> { ... } }`

Comment: What is exactly your use case? What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: @gtxtreme Thanks.  @Sweeper I know the syntax is not right here, I asked if there is support for such multiple conditions. For your question, logically I am thinking if it is `||` then the first condition matches so that will be executed but I get the sense it is kinda outrageous

Comment: @JoãoDias I have a lengthy block of code checking for matches in in two variables of a class and wanted to know if there is a way to shorten it in the aforementioned manner.

Answer (score 3):

You can always do the following, but to be honest, I am not sure a `when` condition is what you need for your use case:

```kotlin
val namesAndRegions = listOf(newVehicle.name, newVehicle.region)
when {
    "Mitsubishi 2" in namesAndRegions -> print("Is Mitsubishi 2")
    "Kenya" in namesAndRegions -> print("Is Kenya")
}
```